# Best practice for GPS-Tracking in iOS with Windows Azure?

Tags: ios, azure, gps, azure-mobile-services

I want to build an iOS application that GPS coordinates from the iPad to a Windows Azure Service.
An asp.net will read this GPS coordinates and show them on a map.

Is there a best practice to do this or should i just write the coordinates in a table and delete old coordinates as soon as newer coordinates will get uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a persistent connection to make this faster instead of the Request-Response model of HTTP.

You can use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/), it's a library for ASP.NET that makes real-time apps really easy. You can use [SignalR-ObjC](https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC) as an iOS client.

Your iOS app sends consistent updates of GPS coordinates. The SignalR backend receives them, and updates the web app.